# How to mock a response to some expected object using CamelTestSupport?

Tags: junit, apache-camel, camel-test

There's a DTO created on a builder method (assume it has only a "name" attribute with some random value) and I want to check if the returned object has the same value, but the response is null.

Unit test code:

```java
class GetProductByIdRouteBuilderTest extends CamelTestSupport {

  @Test
  void testRoute() throws Exception {
    var expected = DTOBuilder.getProductDetailsDTO();

    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedMessageCount(1);
    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedHeaderReceived("id", 1);

    var response = template.requestBodyAndHeader(
            "direct:getProductById",
            null,
            "id",
            1L,
            GetProductDetailsDTO.class
    );

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    assertEquals(expected.getName(), response.getName());
  }

  @Override
  protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() {
        from("direct:getProductById")
            .routeId("getProductById")
            .log("id = ${header.id}")
            .to("mock:result")
        .end();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**Solution**

Used the whenAnyExchangeReceived method:

```java
getMockEndpoint("mock:result").whenAnyExchangeReceived(exchange -> {
    exchange.getMessage().setBody(expected);
    exchange.getMessage().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, HttpStatus.OK.value());
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a totally expected behavior since the body of the original message is `null` and your route doesn't transform it such that the result of your route is `null`.

Let's describe your code step by step to better understand:

1. The test method

The next code snippet, sends a message to the Consumer endpoint `direct:getProductById` with `null` as body and `1L` as value of the header `id` and tries to convert the **resulting body** into an object of type `GetProductDetailsDTO`.

```
var response = template.requestBodyAndHeader(
        "direct:getProductById",
        null,
        "id",
        1L,
        GetProductDetailsDTO.class
);
```

2. The route

Your route simply logs the value of the header `id` and sends the message received by the consumer endpoint `direct:getProductById` **as is** to the producer endpoint `mock:result`.

---

So knowing that, we can see that your route will actually end with a message with `null` as body, and since Camel cannot convert `null` to an object of type `GetProductDetailsDTO`, you end up with `null` as result of your route.

I guess that your route is incomplete as it should somehow query your database.

Comment: Somehow it answered my question. I had to use `whenAnyExchangeReceived` method of `MockEndpoint` class to set the response body.